# Get all rows from the last N days with HBase

Tags: date, hadoop, timestamp, hbase

I'm trying to write a component that fetches rows from HBase from the last 5 days (5 is arbitrary). The timestamp I want to use is the default timestamp HBase gives to rows (unless its problematic for some reason)

I know I can use [scan and with timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242202/get-count-of-hbase-table-based-on-dates) range but I'm not quite sure how to get the current date in HBase (I'm currently testing it in the HBase shell but eventually I need to have a code doing that). I've tried something like this:

```
scan 'urls', {COLUMNS => 'urls', TIMERANGE => [SimpleDateFormat.new("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2016/03/02 00:00:00", ParsePosition.new(0)).getTime(), new Date().getTime()]}
```

but the shell is saying I have a syntax error unexpected tCONSTANT. I did import both Date, SimpleDateFormat and ParsePosition successfully

I also looked at [other examples](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/shell_tricks.html) but could not find exactly what I needed

I was also wondering if there is a more elegant way to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HBase shell you can use TIMERANGE filter. Example from scan --help command:

```
hbase> scan 't1', {COLUMNS => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [1303668804, 1303668904]}
```

For java client, you can set timeRange on the scan object:

```
Scan s = new Scan();
s.setTimeRange(1303668804L, 1303668904L);
```

Comment: I've seen this exact example in some of the links I posted, however, it's not what I need. I'm trying to fetch all the rows from the last N days and I'm not sure how to do this with HBase

Comment: what's not working is I'm not sure how to get the data up to today. It seems like getting today's date is not possible just by doing new Date().getTime()

Comment: @Gideon if there's problem with current date generation, why don't just try to use a bigger number, like a date for 2050 year, since current date is an upper bound?

Comment: I don't mind doing that but I was just wondering if there's a more non-patchy way

Comment: I forgot to accept this, but I ended up doing what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Will this perform a full table scan, filtering rows as it goes?

Comment: @AvivCohn yes, but there are some optimizations, like HFile that contains min and max timestamp of its cells, that can be skipped entirely if it does not much the query